# ImportError: No module named 'xlsxwriter': Error in bamboo

Tags: python-3.x, bamboo, xlsxwriter

I have used pip to install a package named 'xlsxwriter', by using the command 'pip3 install xlsxwriter'.
The code is working fine on my system, but when I am trying to run the same code on bamboo then it throwing an ImportError as "No module named 'xlsxwriter'."
I have used other packages too like argparse and requests, they are working fine but for this particular package bamboo is throwing an error. 
When not using this particular package, the bamboo plan is successfully running, so I believe the requirements and other things for python are fine in bamboo.

Answer (score 0):

1-make sure/or change directory of your windows python 27 or python 33 is C:\Python27

2-download XlsxWriter package ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter )

3-extrat tar file (lookup for tar extractor tool for windows)

4-open cmd

5-go to your downlaoded and extracted package directory

6-type in command prompt: python setup.py install
you can now check module intalled in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
or you could type: sudo pip install xlsxwriter

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am working on Mac and python 3.6 is store in '/usr/local/bin/'. Also, XlsxWriter is already present here - ''/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0.5)"