# Writing out document in GUI executable using cx_freeze not working

Tags: user-interface, executable, cx-freeze, xlsxwriter

I made an executable gui (with tkinter) file using cx_freeze. The executable has several buttons. When the user click the button, the calculation should work and then it will write out an xlsx file.

Everything went good when I make the executable, there was no error. But when I click the button, it seems like the calculation works (since it was loading), but then it does not write out the xlsx file.

I don't know what went wrong. Anyone can help me?

Here's the setup.py file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
import tkinter

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"


executables = [Executable("gui.py", base=base)]

packages = ["tkinter", 'xlsxwriter', 'matplotlib']
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': ["os", "tkinter", 'numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format', 'xlrd', 'scipy', 'pandas'],
        'include_files': [r"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                          r"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]
    },

}

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'


setup(
    name="Tool",
    version="1.0",
    description="Tool prototype for calculating",
    options=options,
    executables=executables
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

What i did was to change the base in setup.py to : base = None

and I installed the xlsxwriter by following this thread: [ImportError: No module named 'xlsxwriter': Error in bamboo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245137/importerror-no-module-named-xlsxwriter-error-in-bamboo)

After this, I encountered another problem:

No module named: scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation

but I simply add this to the 'includes': ['scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation', ...]

now everything works perfectly.

I hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.